# Trying to run Android ADK with my Galaxy S2 (v2.3.6). Demokit giving loads of errors on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I followed each and every step properly given in the ADK website. Downloaded and installed all the libraries. I was trying to run the demokit app given there in eclipse. But i get loads of errors such as:

```
 "The method getAccessory(Intent) is undefined for the type String"  
 "ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED cannot be resolved or is not a field"
 "EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED cannot be resolved or is not a field"
 "Type mismatch: cannot convert from UsbAccessory to UsbAccessoryActivity"
```

These are just some of the errors. Getting many such similar errors. Unable to build it in to my phone.

Just can't figure out what to do....

Comment: I presume from your question that you didn't change anything in the code. In that case I think there is a problem with your installation. Were you able to build any other Android App in eclipse?

Comment: Erm, yeah.. I actually didn't change anything in the code.. I followed the instructions given in android adk website. And yes, I was able to build other apps in eclipse, in the emulator as well as on my phone. I guess eclipse is fine!

Comment: Are all the imports recognized (specifically android.future.usb)? Are you running an official version of Android from Samsung? If so I doubt you will be able to run Android Accessory on it. However Samsung announced the release of IceCream Sandwich for the beginning of march.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the `getAccessory` method. You pass to it a parameter that is `String` and it expects it to be `Intent`. However, we need a piece of your code where the error appears.

Comment: Hey Yury, thanks for your reply. Here are the lines of code where i get an error:

UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);

UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))

else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED.equals(action))

UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);

mUsbManager = UsbManager.getInstance(this);

filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED);